# How can i create displacement vector in circular search window?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

[image]

I have a circular search window for each pixel. To create a displacement vector between the last 1 points of the circle from each center point I can not do. But I have to do this between the center and the end points.

```
img=rand(5,10);

r = 2; % radius

Nsize=size(img,1)*size(img,2);


[R, C] = ndgrid(1 : size(img, 1), 1 : size(img, 2));
k=1;
d=1;
for a=1:size(img,1)
    for b=1:size(img,2)
        coordinate=[a b];

        for kk = 1 : size(coordinate, 1)
            r = coordinate(kk, 1); c = coordinate(kk, 2); % Get the pixel locations
            circular_search_window{d} = (R - r).^2 + (C - c).^2 <= r*r;
            pix{d} =double(img).*circular_search_window{1,k};
            if d<=Nsize
                d=d+1;
            end

            if k<=Nsize
                k=k+1;
            end

        end
    end
end
```

By looking at this code, you can understand better.

Comment: Your code does not seems the be a [mcve]. It is not clear to me what your search windows are.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please clarify rather than posting new duplicate questions.

Comment: i edit my question. İf you don't understand , you can ask me again.

Comment: I don't understand what "the last 1 points of the circle" means. I can't run your code because `coords` is undefined. The rest of it, I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Looking at the matrix above. I mean the (3, 5) point is the center point. I will create a vector from this point (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (4,6), (3,7). How can I get these points in a loop?

Comment: I mean, I have a circular field at each end of the matrix. I just want to get the positions of the corners of this circle